# Risk of constant traffic when updating graphics using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml, performance

I'm using JavaScript to create a basic graphic clock display on an HTML page. I'm updating digit graphics (each digit updated only when necessary) using the standard DOM mechanism:

```
digitOne.src = "file/path/one.png";
```

The clock works fine, but I want to know whether all or some browsers will mindlessly fetch the image from my site every time the src attribute is changed, rather than cache a copy in RAM. I'm worried that in some cases, perhaps in older browsers, viewing the graphic clock will create data traffic constantly and chew through my monthly data allowance.

So I'm hoping someone can tell me whether this is a risk, or point me to a mechanism to swap graphics in JavaScript which guarantees that an existing image will be used from memory rather than trigger a network fetch every time.

(I have hunted around for a definitive answer to this, but couldn't find one. I've not used JavaScript for DHTML since 1999/2000, so I'm a bit behind the times. At least it's no longer necessary to write two versions of every JavaScript function, one for IE4/5 and one for Netscape 4.)

Comment: using a sprite and change only background position?

Comment: I'd rather use a method which will work even if CSS is disabled, for accessibility. (Yes, I am already updating the alt attribute as each digit is changed, but images do not stop displaying if CSS is ignored.)

Comment: If CSS doesn't work in a browser, you can be sure Javascript won't work as well. Use sprites and don't worry about it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you can be *sure*, but to put things in perspective: Firefox has a built-in setting in the Options window to turn off Javascript for *all* pages, while CSS can only be turned off *temporarily* for one page. In general, browsers are more likely to support CSS than to support JS - take a look at e-book readers' browsers.

Comment: As I suspected, it sounds like older versions of IE do misbehave where image caching is concerned. See http://www.ahinea.com/en/tech/ie-dhtml-image-caching.html and also http://mir.aculo.us/2005/08/28/internet-explorer-and-ajax-image-caching-woes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend to you using HTML5 canvas 2D drawing. It not requires any images at all and is currently supported by all newer version of all browsers even in IE. 
Check this out

http://www.neilwallis.com/projects/html5/clock/index.php

Read this simple yet great tutorial:

http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Comment: Several good answers on this page, but I really want to avoid relying on CSS to make up for flaws in JavaScript. And the links in this answer have convinced me that the best option is using the HTML5 canvas element which is designed for animated graphics. (I know that canvas is not supported in IE versions older than 9, but I'm so sick of trying to please outdated versions of IE that I just don't care. At least a canvas element will degrade gracefully in older browsers.)

Comment: If that's the point and you don't need any images...RaphaelJS uses vector graphics. It'll run even on IE6...

Comment: Thank you, Minko. RaphaelJS looks like an excellent piece of kit.

Comment: Just an update in case anyone is interested in the same topic. I created a set of clock digits in SVG format, then used RaphaelJS to render them onto the web page. The problem is that RaphaelJS also does not seem to guarantee that image files aren't constantly loaded from source. Also, I think my SVG files may be too fancy, because the rendering speed is far too slow for a millisecond clock. So back to the drawing board again.

Comment: What is the point of using vector graphic if you still using images?

Comment: Because I can't achieve the look I want with basic vector shapes and I ideally wanted the result to be a generic, fits-any-size display which can be called to fit a space 100x30 or a screen 1600x1200. I'm sure that SVG graphics will fit the bill eventually, but at the moment performance seems to be too poor. So raster graphics will have to do the job, and the result will have to be one-size-only.

Comment: Okay, I think I've found a winner. I rewrote the code for the third time, now using the HTML5 Canvas API. This does allow you to simply draw from an Image object in memory, removing the fear of constant network fetching. To my surprise Canvas can even render from SVG image files (in Firefox 17 at least). And the performance is vastly better than in RaphaelJS. So n.podbielski put me on the right track with the Canvas recommendation. (Though I am disappointed that I had to write a custom image loader to guarantee that Image objects were ready before the code continues.)

Comment: I am glad that I could help. I am just curious. Did you server always respond with all content of static content? It's bit of spaghetti. I am asking if you application server responds with 304 Not Modified HTTP response in some cases?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to worry about the traffic. It's easy to cache the images when initializing the application. Look into my example in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pAwdC/.
When I'm initializing the application I'm calling `loadImages`. This method creates `img` DOM element for each digit. It's `src` is being taken from the array `imagesSrc`. When the `loadImages` function is called the browser is making few HTTP get requests to the server:

[image]

Actually each request is made when:

```
current.src = imagesSrc[i];
```

is executed.

After the images are loaded, I'm just hiding them. When the images are with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` the user cant actually see them but when you make these hidden elements visible no more requests are made, only eventual [repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) are done by the browser. All elements are cached and displayed only when required. You can check your firebug or whatever other dev tool you're using that no more requests for these images are made.

Here is the code from my example:

```
var images = [],
    imagesSrc = ['https://lh3.ggpht.com/-107YXK-eAXs/UB6V49H9yuI/AAAAAAAACsY/69ceZJXaYZE/s1600/number-one-.png',
    'https://lh3.ggpht.com/-8rOrxAwDl48/Txf99Sus18I/AAAAAAAAL1w/VcmeP7rNFwY/s1600/number2c.png',
    'https://lh3.ggpht.com/-aGatHUidcGw/UG6Oh2HdWXI/AAAAAAAADQY/yc1CTC7cpOY/s1600/number3.png'];

function loadImages() {
    var current;
    for (var i = 0; i < imagesSrc.length; i += 1) {
        current = document.createElement('img');
        current.src = imagesSrc[i];
        images.push(current);
        current.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(current);
    }
}

function showImage() {
    var current = showImage.current || 0;
    if (current >= 3) {
        current = 0;
    }
    hideImages();
    images[current].style.display = 'block';
    current += 1;
    showImage.current = current;
    setTimeout(function () {
        showImage();
    }, 1000);
}

function hideImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

loadImages();
showImage();
```

For my example I need just a single instance of each digit. Of course for your clock you can create four instances (four `img` DOM elements) for each digit so that you can show duplicates.

For your application may be better approach will be to load the images on demand, but only once and then cache them. It's good to do this because the user may not stay on your page to see each digit (from 0 to 9) and you may improve a little your performance by this lazy loading. For this strategy you can check the [flyweight pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailflyweight). It's main idea is to manage a set of reusable small objects and use them on demand, while controlling it's creation. Here is a UML class diagram which shows the structure of the pattern:

[image]

There are different variations of the approach I've mentioned. May be the most lightest variation you can do is to use a single image which contains all the digits. After that you can create different elements (for example div) with the size of a digit. When you set to these elements a background with specific position you can create all digits by loading only a single image. This will reduce your requests from 10 to just a single one. This approach is effectively used by facebook, for example.

If you need further assistance I'll be glad to help.
​

Answer (score 1):

If CSS is enabled, the following pattern works. I'm presenting this one because it's a bit clearer than the solution if it's not.

```
<div id='clock'>
  <div id='digit0' style="display:block"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div id='digit1' style="display:none"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div id='digit2' style="display:none"><!-- ... --></div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

To change the digit display, hide the currently visible digit and make visible the next one. The JavaScript-only solution is related. Make a single invisible `<div>` to hide the invisible digits. Add and remove individual digit `<div>` elements, swapping the old digit from the clock display with the next digit from the digit storehouse element.

Both these solutions have the behavior that images within the DOM subtrees are only fetched once, because the subtrees are never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be absolutely sure, you could generate the HTML element with the image of the digit and place it to the page with `display: none`, so it's already loaded and on the page.

If the digit is being needed, you first check for the HTML element on the page and take this one, set it to `display: block` or whatever you need and replace the current digit element with that one.

As some sample code, I've just put this together.

var digit_images = ["file/path/one.png", "file/path/two.png", "file/path/three.png", ...];

```
function giveMeTheDigit(digit)
{
    var img = digit_images[digit];
    var element = $("#digit_holder" + digit);

    if (element.length == 1)
    {
        $(".digit_holder").hide(); //hide the current holder
        element.show(); //show the new one
    }
    else
    {
        $('<div class="digit_holder" id="digit_holder' + digit + '"><img src="' + img + '" /></div>')
            .appendTo("#yourDestination");
    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but I think you know what I'm after and could edit this to your needs. Good luck!